# How to get rid of faint borders in Stata -by()- graph

Tags: graph, stata

When I plot graphs I usually need white background. 
Sometimes the problem is to get rid of "faint" borders and it's not hard to get rid of them by playing with the plot options.

However, I really cannot get rid of such borders when I plot a `by` graph.
See for instance:

```
sysuse auto, clear
hist mpg, by(foreign, plotregion(fcolor(white)) graphregion(fcolor(white) ifcolor(white) color(white) icolor(white)) bgcolor(white))
```

How to eliminate the lines around the two graphs here?
Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try either of these:

```
hist mpg, by(foreign, graphregion(color(white) lwidth(large)))
hist mpg, by(foreign, bgcolor(white) graphregion(color(white)))
```

The logic behind this is explained [here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2003-09/msg00507.html).